# Multiple PGP keys on one server

Tags: encryption, pgp

I have a server on which we are planning to expire the current PGP keys later this year. Now we have several clients which are currently using that PGP key. We want to have another new PGP key pair and keep it active with the current PGP key pair so that we can move the customers first to the new one and then expire the old one. Is it possible to have two active PGP key pairs on one system? If yes, then how can we manage them and how will the system identify them, if the files are coming with different key pairs?

Comment: Yes, but how about you just read what I suppose to be the GPG user manual? Usually, you sign the new key with the old, upload both to the servers (or distribute them otherwise) and use the new key for signing and encryption from that point on - keeping the old one around to be able to decrypt messages from people using the old key.